# When null is returned I want the query to pull the most recent non-null value

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query to make a chart of a specific product we are currently making.  So every time the query runs it pulls the most recent value (time) and for whatever reason sometime a null will sneak in from time to time.  Is there a way to say pull the most recent value if its not null and if it is null then go back and pull the most recent non null value.

FYI I'm using SQL

Thanks

```
select 
       CASE
    WHEN Val = 1 THEN 'MJ'
       WHEN Val = 2 THEN 'SL'
       WHEN Val = 3 THEN 'TY'
       WHEN Val = 4 THEN 'HYD'
       WHEN Val = 5 THEN 'MET'
       WHEN Val = 6 THEN 'UP'
       WHEN Val = 7 THEN 'TR'       
       END as Val 
from CM5Float
where DateAndTime in ( SELECT MAX(DateAndTime) from CM5Float) and TagIndex = 26
```

Comment: Val is just the column name and null is like returning "nothing" or zero

Comment: I know what null is. You wrote "if it is null" and I was just wondering what "it" is.